# How to get all Facebook friend list with iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

Here it's my code:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Here it's the response, only have one `FBUser` in data but have `pagingField`, how should I get next page?

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "first_name" = Joe;
            id = 1410250212552901;
            "last_name" = Sadanwitz;
            name = "Joe Amgjchjgcigg Sadanwitz";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1410250212552901/friends?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name&format=json&access_token=CAAEY8AAUoPcBAExJCteA2ZBZBcqeQnkDBLBhQy2T1ghNofZAU5wT0KinVAXyjeDBOlzrRl3ZBCTAbmyHqrjU4f6JKJrBZCSECZBvvLcoDUJshY5NnZCxZBHkZBCKgWUzVyJAZAQUGoaEffcjokL28wN0Xpn8FuNs5drHpe2BTrCJsCMHpU7x85N2V86qVT1Pnx85xC1ffhoG6tRvzpTBdz9vi1shb5SUeqtlinAofI7lU52AZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AexOP9huSQ39Ccrt9AIumeBtqGnFH8RnliwvpPwisb4b9dH46LFTaVWVp1c-lYoncilrxvDQ2XFY7KK7o642UiF_";
    };
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 9;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way.

> App Friends: The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list
>   of a person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that
>   person's friends who are also using your app.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/).

Comment: Yes, I just found that.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for invitable friends if you writing a game with this code

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/invitable_friends"
                         parameters:nil
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2